# A translator that replaces vowels with a string

Tags: python

For those that don't know, replacing vowels with 'ooba' has become a popular trend on https://reddit.com/r/prequelmemes . I would like to automate this process by making a program with python 2.7 that replaces vowels with 'ooba'. I have no idea where to get started

Comment: This sounds dumb, but your request is simple: `new_word = ''.join(['ooba' if l in 'aeiou' else l for l in old_word])`

Comment: @KevinK. you can leave out the `[]`, ie. use a generator expression instead of the list comprehension. You should post this as an answer. Also I (and pep8) suggest not to use `l` as a variable name

Comment: If the word is `queue`, should the program output `qooba`, or do you really want it to output `qoobaoobaoobaooba`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regular expression:

```
import re

my_string = 'Hello!'
my_other_string = re.sub(r'[aeiou]', 'ooba', my_string)

print(my_other_string)  # Hooballooba!
```

Answer (score 1):

Following method is suggested if the line is short. I would prefer using regex otherwise. Following assumes that your text is `s`.

```
s = ''.join(['ooba' if i in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] else i for i in s])
```

Regex approach:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'a|e|i|o|u', "ooba", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and simple answer, you could feed string `meme` into here

```
for i, c in enumerate(meme):
  if c in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
    meme[:i] = meme[:i] + 'ooba' + meme[i+1:]
```

It goes over each character in the string, and checks if it is a vowel. If it is, it slices around the index and inserts 'ooba' where it used to be.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.